# tail the last modified file and monitor for new files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I can `tail -f` the last modified file using `ls --sort=time | head -1 | xargs tail -f` but I'm looking for something that would continuously run the first part as well, i.e. if a new files is created while the tail command is running it switches to tailing the new file. I thought about using `watch` command but that doesn't seem to work nicely with `tail -f`

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/956311/continuously-detect-new-files-with-inotify-tools-within-multiple-directories-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TAILPID=0
WATCHFILE=""

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT     # Makes sure we clean our mess (background processes) on exit

while true
do
    NEWFILE=`ls --sort=time | head -n 1`
    if [ "$NEWFILE" != "$WATCHFILE" ]; then

            echo "New file has been modified"
            echo "Now watching: $NEWFILE";
            WATCHFILE=$NEWFILE
            if [ $TAILPID -ne 0 ]; then
                    # Kill old tail
                    kill $TAILPID
                    wait $! &> /dev/null # supress "Terminated" message 
            fi
            tail -f $NEWFILE &
            TAILPID=$!      # Storing tail PID so we could kill it later
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This has the obvious problem that you are parsing `ls` and assuming that file names never contain a newline. A more robust solution would use `find` and, of course, [properly quote any variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) which contains a file name. But this has been beaten to death many times; go look for duplicates.